# How to make multiple indices as NaN in a vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector x = [1 2 3 ...100]. I need to make NAN only certain indices. I am doing:

```
 x(1)=NaN;
 x(2)=NaN; 
 x(98)=NaN;
```

I also tried

```
x([1:3],[97:100])=NaN;
```

But this one did not work. I know indices which need to be put NaN. How to do it in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab, you should use `()` for indexing:

```
X = [1:100];
X(1) = NaN;
X(2) = NaN;
X(98) = NaN;
X(1:3) = NaN; X(97:100) = NaN;
```

EDIT, or just using one line:

```
X([1:3, 97:100]) = NaN;
```

Comment: Why can't I do it in one line?

Comment: @MelB I have added a one-line solution.